# Does webauthn support mutual authentication?

Tags: webauthn

Does webauthn provide any authentication of the server end?

Or asked differently, is there any defense against a man-in-the-middle attack that pretends to be site X, performs what looks like a webauthn login to that site, always grants access, and now the users think they just logged into site X yet are talking to a middle-man?
(I know the man-in-the-middle can't get to the password or token.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do FIDO keys prevent MITM reflection attacks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/206543/how-do-fido-keys-prevent-mitm-reflection-attacks). In short: WebAuthn relies in a TLS connection to the server which includes authenticating of the server. It does not add any server authentication on top of it - except that the used key is bound to the (via TLS) authenticated domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in [the question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/206543/how-do-fido-keys-prevent-mitm-reflection-attacks) that [@SteffenUllrich linked](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/269318/does-webauthn-support-mutual-authentication#comment559889_269318), the security model for webauthn is based on the assumption that it is only used in a "secure" context, which for browsers means "page and all content on it loaded over HTTPS", and HTTPS requires server authentication (there are some old SSL/TLS cipher suites that don't require server authentication, but none of them are permitted by browsers). As such, the webauthn specification requires that the webauthn API only be exposed through HTTPS.

To quote [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#sctn-api):

> The client facilitates these security measures by providing the [Relying Party](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#relying-party)'s [origin](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#concept-origin) and [RP ID](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#rp-id) to the [authenticator](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#authenticator) for each operation. Since this is an integral part of the WebAuthn security model, user agents only expose this API to callers in [secure contexts](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/#secure-contexts). For web contexts in particular, this only includes those accessed via a secure transport (e.g., TLS) established without errors.

Therefore, while webauthn does not technically support mutual authentication itself, it can only be used in a context where the server is already authenticated, and thus it only needs to provide for client authentication.